# Ruby on Rails redirect in routes with changed url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have path like

```
www.domain.com/*?​_escaped_fragment_​=
```

and I want to redirect it (301) to the same path without ending `?_escaped_fragment_​=`

What I have so far is:

```
get "*path", constraints: { path: /\?​_escaped_fragment_​=/ }, to: redirect { |params, request| binding.pry && request.env['HTTP_REFERER'].split('?​_escaped_fragment_​=').first  }, status: 301
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In that action you could simply say

```
 if params["_escaped_fragment_"].present?
   redirect_to wherever_you_want_them_to_go
 end
```

Another option would be to take the request url and parse / manipulate the string but seems unnecessary.